# Automatically create child object from parent - Django 1.11

Tags: python, django

I have a parent class:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
     field1 = model.CharField()
     field2 = model.CharField()
```

And a child:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    pass
```

Is there a possible way to create a child object whenever a perent is saved?

The child inherits all the fields from the parent, but, regardless if filled or not, I would need to create a new child object whenever a parent is saved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let them use the same database table? Pretty unusual thing to want to do though.

Comment: Absolutely is, but what can I say... do You have any example that you could use as an answer? Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can use signals or you can override **save** method of **Parent** model to do that.

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Parent)
def post_parent_save(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    # Create child here
```

Or,

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Parent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create child here
```

In both options, if you want to create a child only when a parent is **created** (not **updated**), you need to add extra login. For signals, you can use the created parameter, for overriding save method, you need to check if the model instance has an id field before calling super save method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if something like this would work for you:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'whateverappparentisin_parent'
        managed = False
```

I'm not sure what Django would do with this, but the idea is that you get a model with the exact same fields, backed by the same database table (so everything else e.g. deletes on Parent would also immediately be "visible" on Child1), without Django wanting to make migrations for it.

But I don't know if it's allowed.